# How to make map specific to few countries

Tags: r, dictionary, spatial

I needed to map the number of cases in my data from south Asia only..
I found this code related to Africa.

```
africa = world %>% 
  filter(continent == "Africa", !is.na(iso_a2)) %>% 
  left_join(worldbank_df, by = "iso_a2") %>% 
  dplyr::select(name, subregion, gdpPercap, HDI, pop_growth) %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25")
```

I tweaked it a little bit but the map it shows is of full Asia. How can I narrow it down to south Asia only ??

```
asia = world %>% 
  filter(continent == "Asia", !is.na(iso_a2)) %>% 
  left_join(worldbank_df, by = "iso_a2") %>% 
  dplyr::select(name, subregion, gdpPercap, HDI, pop_growth) %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25")
```

Comment: What library is this from?

Comment: Could `subregion` or `region_un` have that information already? Could you show a snippet of the dataset?

Comment: my data has a column named as region.
(worldbanl_df) has following columns

name               iso_a2    HDI urban…¹ unemp…² pop_g…³ liter…⁴

Comment: Which South Asia countries are you trying to analyze?

Comment: Bangladesh, India, Pakistan, Nepal, Sri Lanka, and Afghanistan

Comment: If it's just those six, what about `filter(name %in% c("Bangladesh", "India", "Pakistan", "Nepal", "Sri Lanka", "Afghanistan")`? (I'm assuming `name` contains country names)

Comment: And now, write up the code that worked as an answer to help others in the future. Welcome to the Stackoverflow process.

Answer (score 1):

```
asia = world %>% 
  filter(continent == "Asia", !is.na(iso_a2)) %>%
  left_join(worldbank_df, by = "iso_a2") %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Pakistan", "Afghanistan", "Srilanka", "India"))  %>%
  dplyr::select(name, subregion, gdpPercap, HDI, pop_growth) %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=aea +lat_1=10 +lat_2=-20 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10")
```